# Open source alternative of Acrobat Editor to prepare a PDF form (eg a smart resume) which can be filled out by the recipients

Tags: pdf, linux-mint

I am looking for an open source alternative to`Acrobat Editor` to prepare `PDF` forms which can be filled out by the recipient. So far I tried `pdf editor` in `Linux mint 14` but it didn't work. 
Does anyone know of an `open source alternative` to create forms? Tips or a tutorial would be apreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should take a look at these:

http://itsfoss.com/edit-pdf-and-xps-files-in-ubuntu-linux-with-master-pdf-editor-free/

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1377562&page=2

And here is a big list of Open Source alternatives:

http://www.cogniview.com/convert-pdf-to-excel/post/pdf-editing-creation-50-open-sourcefree-alternatives-to-adobe-acrobat/